# To what extent is schema evolution available in ORC files in Hive 0.13?

Tags: hadoop, hive, database-schema, orc

Are the changes in schema like adding, deleting, renaming, modifying data type in columns permitted without breaking anything in ORC files in Hive 0.13.

Comment: Tried running an `ALTER TABLE` command yourself?

Comment: Yup, I tried adding columns and it turned out okay. But then read on internet that schema evolution is not supported in Hive 0.13. So I thought that though columns were added data may break. Thats the reason for this question.

Comment: I believe schema evolution is enforced at the file storage layer, not really at the Hive query layer since it's schema-on-read.